# Overlay the Android camera app aka the barcode scanner

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

When the Android camera opens it fills up the screen in width and height but actually I want the app to open and limit upto certain dimensions on the screen aka [BarCode Scanner](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_QtI8kn0v-ZU/SgHe_mgGhqI/AAAAAAAAA68/jm8C6ZzGEj4/BCSanner2.png) but here the catch is that the image taken should limit the boundary of the rectangle that the app shows on its surface.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: That app is open-source, so feel free to check what they are doing:

[Project on google code](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

If i had a guess I'd say they overlay the camera preview with another view (e.g. via addContentView()) and crop the camera-/previewimage after the image callback.
So this is definitely possible, you have to crop the image manually though (according to the frame).